# GUI test for an app written mainly with Tcl/Tk

Tags: user-interface, testing, tcl, tk-toolkit

Would really appreciate your help with Tcl/Tk testing framework. I am supposed to test a windows application written with Tcl/Tk, twapi, gdi 0.9.5.1. Do you know a black-box and/or white-box test framework that will help me with GUI testing (generate mouse event, etc etc, and drive the application)? What I expect from the test framework is something like what WindowsLicker allows you to do for Swing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tk can generate events with the `event generate` command, but it will only send these events to itself. You can combine these with the `tcltest` package to do such testing as you require.

That said, I actually advise splitting up your code so that there is a clear separation between the GUI and the functionality that powers it (the “business logic layer”, to borrow a phrase from server architectures). You can then test your baseline functionality thoroughly without having to fiddle around with testing GUIs, which is *enormously* easier. Once your BLL is working robustly, testing your GUI then becomes a matter of ensuring that actions in the GUI manipulate the view correctly or translate into appropriate BLL calls (which you know will either work correctly or fail in a way that is clear).

Comment: One of the reasons that testing a GUI is difficult is that “correctness” is often a matter of perception; having the button be technically clickable is no good if it's just 1x1 in size, and the computer doesn't know what a garish combination of colors is at all…

Comment: Indeed to test any interface you need the components on both sides of it. For a UI then one side of the interface is a user ;)

Comment: Thanks for the answers @DonalFellows! I am looking more towards ensuring that actions in the GUI manipulate the view correctly. Something that is like a black box acceptance test (we've passed the unit test and integration test..). Would the tcltest help me with that and what is the difficulty level of creating the test script for someone whose background is more of Java, Matlab and a little bit of C?

Comment: i was hoping there was a way i could automate some functions @jk but you're right at the end of the day someone's still going to sit and interact with the software to test if it's working properly.

Comment: @oalah, I would also look at the test suite of the Tk itself (found in the `tests` directory in the source tree) -- it uses the standard `tcltest` suite to drive the GUIs.

Comment: I also wonder if its possible to make `tcltest` spawn the application to be tested and then somehow use `event generate` via calls to [`send`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/send.htm).